# Breadcrumb selector for list items with a list item beside

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Ive created a breadcrumb you can see the code here http://jsfiddle.net/zgx5qcsx/

I need a CSS selector to give the &:after &:before to all but the last li but have not been able to figure this out - currently clumsily I have got:

```
li:first-child,
li:first-child + li
```

This is not ideal because as more steps are added ill have to amend!

Any suggestions will be much appreciated

```
.breadcrumb
{
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
background-color: light-grey;
li 
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 33.33333333%;
    a 
    {
        &:link, &:visited
        {
            position: relative;
            width: auto;
            display: block;
            // border-right: 1px solid grey;
            @include x-rem(padding, 20px 20px 20px 50px);
            text-decoration: none;
            span 
            {
                background-color: orange;
                color: white;
            }
        }
    }
}
li:first-child,
li:first-child + li 
{
    a
    {
        &:after
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: -40px;
            display: block;
            content: "";
            border-top: 29px solid transparent;
            border-left: 30px solid light-grey;
            border-bottom: 29px solid transparent;
            border-right: 10px solid transparent;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        &:before
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: -41px;
            display: block;
            content: "";
            border-top: 29px solid transparent;
            border-left: 30px solid grey;
            border-bottom: 29px solid transparent;
            border-right: 10px solid transparent;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        &.breadcrumb--active
        {
            background-color: white;
            &:after
            {
                border-left: 30px solid white;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can use `last-child` and set `display` to `none`. Or you can use `li:not(:last-child)`

Comment: If the site is public, I also advise to check this out http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 and make sure that the CSS will most likely work for the target audience.

Comment: for info li + li it's same that li:first-child + li, you can put you style to everybody after first if you put it at left instead of right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i said before `li + li` is the same as `li:first-child + li` (you can do stuff like `& + li` inside your li if you want of course). Here's my solution - i changed selector and align all the stuff to left.

```
.breadcrumb
{
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: lightgray;  // watch out it's lightgray not light-grey :)
    li 
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        width: 33.33333333%;
        a 
        {
            &:link, &:visited
            {
                position: relative;
                width: auto;
                display: block;
                // border-right: 1px solid grey;
                @include x-rem(padding, 20px 20px 20px 50px);
                text-decoration: none;
                span 
                {
                    background-color: orange;
                    color: white;
                }
            }
            &.breadcrumb--active //changed
            {
                background-color: white;
                &:after
                {
                    border-left: 30px solid grey;
                    z-index: 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    li + li //changed
    {
        a
        {

            &:after
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0; //changed
                display: block;
                content: "";
                border-top: 29px solid transparent;
                border-left: 30px solid lightgray;
                border-bottom: 29px solid transparent;
                border-right: 10px solid transparent;
                z-index: 1; //changed
            }
            &:before
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: -1px; //changed
                display: block;
                content: "";
                border-top: 29px solid transparent;
                border-left: 30px solid white; //changed
                border-bottom: 29px solid transparent;
                border-right: 10px solid transparent;
                z-index: 2; //changed
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[Jsfiddle result](http://jsfiddle.net/zgx5qcsx/2/)